# Typescript Mapped type without right-hand side, wtf?

Tags: typescript

I found myself in a situation where my React component has a lot of methods to toggle state boolean properties.
So, since these functions do all the same thing, I wanted to create a common function to toggle properties.

**Every method** does this:

```js
toggleProperty() {
    this.setState(previous => ({
        myProperty: !previous.myProperty
    }))
}
```

So I came out with a common method that I can call with the context:

```js
/** Filters out keys of B that doesn't have the same type of T **/

type FilterOutUnmatchedType<B extends Object, T extends any> = {
    [K in keyof B]: B[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof B];


private StateToggler(this: Configurator, property: FilterOutUnmatchedType<ConfiguratorState, boolean>) {
        this.setState((previous) => ({
            [property]: !previous[property]
        });
    }
```

So what I did here was that I wanted to accept only boolean properties from my state in this function. `FilterOutUnmatchedType` works well, but VSCode gave me this error:

```
Argument of type '(previous: Readonly<ConfiguratorState>) => { [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConfiguratorState | ((prevState: Readonly<ConfiguratorState>, props: Readonly<ConfiguratorProps>) => ConfiguratorState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.
  Type '(previous: Readonly<ConfiguratorState>) => { [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Readonly<ConfiguratorState>, props: Readonly<ConfiguratorProps>) => ConfiguratorState | Pick<...>'.
    Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ConfiguratorState | Pick<ConfiguratorState, (omitted, keyof ConfiguratorState - basically))>'.
      Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ConfiguratorState, (omitted, keyof ConfiguratorState - basically)>
```

So for what I see, it considers `[property]: boolean` like it is too generic, even if `property` belongs to `keyof ConfiguratorState`.

So I tried so hard (and didn't get so far) to make my object being recognized as part of ConfiguratorState.

I casually came out with a solution that I cannot explain to myself how does it work (but it works) and that I don't know how to look for it online.

```js
this.setState(
    (previous) => ({
        [property]: !previous[property]
    } as { [K in keyof ConfiguratorState] })
);
```

So, this syntax for what I know belongs to Mapped Types... but I expected it to have the right-hand side!
But if I add the RHS like `ConfiguratorState[K]`, it doesn't work. I cannot explain it to me but it seems to work correctly.

Can anyone give me more information about what is this and where I can find more information about this, please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide a right hand side, then its type is implied to be `any`. So, `{ [K in keyof ConfiguratorState] }` is equivalent to `{[K in keyof ConfiguratorState]: any}`, or `Record<ConfiguratorState, any>`. Note that with `noImplicitAny` enabled, typescript will error complaining about the implied `any` type.

[Playground link showing this off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/PTAEFsHsFcGcFNSQG7wE6gGKUqALrgogJZ6z4CeADvAFB7WLa4C8oA3raKANoDSoYgDtQABlAAfUAEYAurQC+AblpA).

Comment: Thank you very much. So, do you think there is a way to mark those props as part of `ConfiguratorState`?